# ActionMailer delivery when following parameters met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Forgive me for asking what i believe is quite an in depth challenge (well for me at the moment anyway)

I have a small app that allows users to check in, check out and hopefully receive emails when a book has been checked back in by registering their interest via a remind me button

So far I have setup actionmailer (basic setup)

```
class ReminderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "email address"

def remind_email(book)
@book = book
@url = "http://localhost:3000"
mail(:to => @book.user.email, :subject => "Book Reminder")


end
```

I have all the config in place to send the emails as I am already doing that through devise.

I have also created the mailer templates. It is the logic I am stuck with.

So when a User checks a book out i pass this back to the model

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
<%= f.label :checked_out, "Check Book Out?" %>
<%= f.check_box :checked_out, {}, true %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :checked_out, :value => true %>
<%= f.submit 'Checkout' %>
<% end %>
```

Check In

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
<%= f.label :checked_out, "Check Book Back In" %>
<%= f.check_box :checked_out, {checked: false}, false  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => nil %>
<%= f.hidden_field :checked_out, :value => false %>
<%= f.submit 'Check In' %>
<% end %>
```

Register Interest

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
<%= f.label :remind_me, "let Me know when book back in" %>
<%= f.check_box :remind_me, {checked: false}, false  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :remind_me, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit 'Remind Me' %>
<% end %>
```

So my thinking is that when you register your interest your user id gets placed into the remind_me column, and what i want to achieve is that when the checked_out field is false and  book.user_id is back to nil I would like the email to send the the user whos user_id is in the remind_me column

Am i thinking about this in the correct way?

if anyone can help it would be appreciated so that i can learn from this and then keep practicing it until I understand what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to answer:

The first one, don't use a form to check in a book and just call a method. For example: You replace your form with a link which call a new method in your controller:

```
<%= link_to "check in", check_in_book_path(@book.id) %>
```

In your books_controller you call a model method which check in the book:

```
def check_in
  @book = Book.find params[:id]
  @book.check_in!
  redirect_to book_path(@book)
end
```

In your book model:

```
def check_in!
  self.user = nil
  self.checked_out = false
  if self.save
    RemindMailer.remind_mail(self).deliver
  end
end
```

Don't forget to add the route for your new controller method.

The second way, if you keep your form, is shorter but more complicated. You need to add a callback to your model which will verify if the data changed. For example, in you book model:

```
after_save :send_mail_if_check_in

def send_mail_if_check_in
  if !self.checked_out && self.changes[:user_id] && self.user.nil?
    RemindMailer.remind_mail(self).deliver
  end
end
```

I prefer the first solution because it seems to be a state machine which is more maintenable.

I hope this help

Comment: thanks for your answer, ive accepted as it has cleared up a lot about the logic behind the process, only trouble now is i cant get the email to the user who clicked remind me, i used option 2 as it made more sense to me